# Creating database tables regarding Primary and Foreign Keys

Tags: sql, key

I'm doing an activity online where I need to create an example database for an Airline. It details the general information needed to be put into each table but I need help linking certain tables.

I've drawn up tables in Word to help me grasp the connections between tables but I'm unsure if I'm doing it correctly.

I have a table called 'Staff' that looks like this:
[image]

I was asked to create another table that provides each staff members previous work experience such as the company they worked for and join and end dates, etc.
The 'Work Experience' table:
[image]

My question is, what would be the primary key for the Work Experience table? Seeing as Staff_ID references back to the Staff table could it be both a Primary Key and a Foreign Key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create a generic work_experience_id or we_id(whatever you way you want it) so that every time you want to call previous work experience for staff you just select generic id primary key.

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply. Got a question though, how will that uniquely identify a staff members work experience? Say I  make the primary key we_ID in the work experience table, how can you determine what staff member matches their work experience seeing as there is no Staff_ID in the work experience table.

Comment: That's where your foreign keys comes in to do the work. Its either you do your current table with Staff_ID as fkey to uniquely identify or throw we_id into table staff to uniquely identify staff member. I'm also new to the whole programming and developing thing and got really confused before on how foreign key works.

Comment: Oh my bad I get it now. Thanks

Comment: Glad i could help somehow.